# Material UI text Field zooms screen on mobile causing screen to cut off top content and showing page bottom

Tags: css, material-ui, frontend, textfield, responsiveness

Every time I click on the Material UI text Field on login after I login the screen is pushed down cutting down content on the top of the page. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovGEz.png)

-I checked my CSS thinking maybe because I set my container height to 100vh but that is not the reason.
-I added CSS for screen ratio below 450 to reduce the height to 80vh but still now solution the page doesn't go back to how it was after typing on text Field

```
.app-container .unauthorised-view,
.not-found-view,
.login {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url('../../public/static/media/bg_unauth.jpg');
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center center;
  background-color: #ededed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

-To resolve the screen always zooming when material ui textfileld and dropdown is clicked, I updated my index.html file with  `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">`

-To resolve the problem where the page shifts or is scrolled downwards cutting off top content i added this on my App.js file   `useEffect(() => { window.scrollTo(0, 0); });`